# How to keep individual grid column height in tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

In the below example (see the tailwind play here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/wUWT1PCfEU), if the first `<details>` is open, the height of the other columns will increase with it.

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-3">
  <div class="bg-gray-400">
    <details>
      <summary>aaaa</summary>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in dui vitae nunc porta finibus eu ut turpis. Donec rhoncus, mauris at fringilla ullamcorper, nibh lacus laoreet sapien, non viverra lectus diam non dolor.
    </details>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-green-400">
    <details>
      <summary>bbbb</summary>
      A small text
    </details>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-purple-400">
    <details>
      <summary>cccc</summary>
      A medium text
    </details>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can this be prevent and each column has individual height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it with tailwind `flex`. Consider the code snippet below:

```
<div class="flex w-full">
  <div class="bg-gray-400 w-4/12 h-full">
    <details>
      <summary>aaaa</summary>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in dui vitae nunc porta finibus eu ut turpis. Donec rhoncus, mauris at fringilla ullamcorper, nibh lacus laoreet sapien, non viverra lectus diam non dolor.
    </details>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-green-400 w-4/12 h-full">
    <details>
      <summary>bbbb</summary>
      A small text
    </details>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-purple-400 w-4/12 h-full">
    <details>
      <summary>cccc</summary>
      A medium text
    </details>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Working Example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/cdGPUTPQWj)